# Close file handle in list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Let's say I want to read in all the lines from a file and store as a 
list of strings. 
I can use:

```
filename = "/path/to/the/file/data.txt"
fileBuf = [line.strip() for line in open(filename, "r")]
```

My question is, because the file handle is unnamed, how do I close it?
Is it closed automatically?

Comment: You have to open it outside the list comprehension, and close it outside the list comprehension.

Comment: another oneline with context: `with open(filename, "r") as f: fileBuf = [line.strip() for line in f]`

Comment: Ok, so I cannot do something like `open(filename, "r").close()` and force this to be executed on exit?

Comment: @izaak_pyzaak no, that would operate on a different file object

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre that should be an answer

Comment: On CPython this shouldn't be a problem, but that's an implementation detail, and not to be relied upon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is probably garbage collected, but recommended way is to use `with` context. You could even do it in one line:

```
with open(filename, "r") as f: fileBuf = [line.strip() for line in f]
```

Comment: So, this is effectively a code block, due to the colon, so it would be scoped and the problem is solved?

Comment: next line you're guaranteed that the file is closed. try `f.close()` you'll see :)

Comment: Good stuff. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `with` statement
Code :

```
with open(FILENAME, 'r') as f:
     fileBuf = [line.strip() for line in f]
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: The user's question was: "...because the file handle is unnamed, how do I close it? Is it closed automatically?"

Comment: @AlexLuisArias: I don't see why you are harsh here, but do not comment on the other answer (which is exactly the same).

Comment: We both added at the same time, and i was not aware that onother user is also gonna write the same. Thanks @Willem Van Onsem for understanding ! :)

Comment: I didn't mean to be harsh! The other answer said that the file will be garbage collected.